# Azure batch pool does not allocate nodes

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have created an azure batch account using "user subscription" allocation mode in order to control the network where my nodes will belong. The objective is to be able to open some firewalls for the set of IP that the nodes may take.

I had been using "batch service" allocation mode before without any trouble but it forces security breach because you have to open your firewalls to all azure if you want to access other services from batch.

The problem I am facing is that no matter what I try (be it Autoscale formula or just a fixed target node count) I never get any node allocated to my pool.

The only message I get is: `AllocationTimedout: Desired number of dedicated nodes could not be allocated as the resize timeout was reached.`

I checked the timeout (which is set to 10 minutes the default value) and I expect azure to be able to create nodes in less than 10 minutes (in "batch service" mode, it is much quicker).

I also checked my virtual machine quota and it is enough to create at least one node (it could create even more).

The problem I am facing is that I think the timeout is not the issue. It is the consequence of something not working in the background.

I checked the Activity log of batch and can see errors:
Write Deployments and Write VirtualMachineScaleSets.
The first seems to be linked to the second and the second state:

```
Error code
InvalidParameter
Message
Windows computer name prefix cannot be more than 9 characters long, be entirely numeric, or contain the following characters: ` ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) = + _ [ ] { } \ | ; : . ' " , < > / ?.
```

What am I missing here? The nodes names are given by Azure batch, not by me and they are indeed very long on standard "batch service" allocation mode.

Comment: I got an answer from azure support team. It was a bug on their side which is now resolved.